# Sorting large CSV in D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to sort a medium sized CSV file (~3000 lines) using D3.js before passing it to a visualization algorithm.

[image]

Apparently though there's something wrong with my code as the sorting seems to be applied in 'chunks' - see the image above. I'm using this d3 function:

```
            dataset.sort(function(a,b) {
              return d3.descending(a.counttotal, b.counttotal);
          });
```

Here's the code:

```
    // Your D3 code will go here
    // safe way to load data 

    var dataset = [];
    d3.csv("subjects.csv",
            function(error, rows) {
                rows.forEach(function(r) {
                    dataset.push({
                        label: r.label,
                        counttotal: r.counttotal
                    })
                });
                generateVis();
            });


    function generateVis(){


        var h = dataset.length * 100; //7000;
        var w = 1000;


        dataset.sort(function(a,b) {
              return d3.descending(a.counttotal, b.counttotal);
          });


        var svg = d3.select("#svg-rect").append("svg")
            .attr('id','mySVG')
            .attr("width", w )
            .attr("height", h);

        var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .enter()
                   .append("rect");           

        rects.attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function(d, i){
                return i * 10 + 10;
            })
            .attr("width", function(d){
                return d.counttotal;
            })
            .attr("height", 8)
            .append("title")
            .text(function (d){
                return d.label + " has " + d.counttotal + " articles ";
            })


    };
```

The CSV file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kwzwqbgts8z2lh/subjects.csv?dl=0

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort function was sorting alphabetically. Convert the totals to numbers first...

```
dataset.sort(function(a,b) {
          return d3.descending(+a.counttotal, +b.counttotal);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd assumed those were numbers in the first place (still learning javascript sorry).